# application partition on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have lunched AWS linus2 AMI  and  created database and setupAjax/ LAMP through puTTY web page in browser.Now I want to partition the application so that application itself is on one instance and the database resides on a database instance on ec2?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: I have completed upto point 3. I want to complete question 4.Can you share me the link, so that I can perform question 4. 

1. Create a simple database on EC2 which will contain three tables
2. Populate all tables
3. Write a couple of Web pages which use AJAX. One should allow the user to lookup all the orders for a customer. The other should list all items.
4. Partition the application so that the application itself is on one instance and the database resides on a database instance.

Comment: Oh, it's an assignment? Part 4 would involve launching an Amazon EC2 instance, installing the database of your choice, and programming your app to connect to the database. You'll also need to open the Security Group on the database instance to accept the incoming connection.

Answer (score 0):

A typical architecture on AWS is:

- An Amazon EC2 instance with the application, placed in a Public Subnet
- An Amazon RDS database

The application on the EC2 instance can connect to the Amazon RDS database. The benefit of this architecture is that the EC2 instance can be updated and even replaced without impacting data stored in the database. Plus, if your application later grows to multiple EC2 instances, they can all communicate with the database.

Using an Amazon RDS database is preferable to running your own database on an Amazon EC2 instance because AWS takes care of deployment, updates and backups.